# How can I dynamically construct a document element string using a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, syntax, document

This is driving me nuts, and I'm sure it's both possible and surely simple to do.

I have a page with a whole bunch of dynamically created forms on it. In one of my functions, I need to access one of those forms, so I pass the name of the form in a variable.

Then I need to access the name of that form using the document tree.

However, when I put in the variable, it assumes the name of the variable is the name of the form.

So this does not work:

```
function myAwesomeFunction(nameOfForm)
{
 var selection = document.nameOfForm.nameOfInput.selectedIndex;
}
```

So I looked around the net and saw that I need to use bracket notation, but this doesn't work either:

```
function myAwesomeFunction(nameOfForm)
{
 var selection = document[nameOfForm].nameOfInput.selectedIndex;
}
```

I also tried with some quotation action:

```
function myAwesomeFunction(nameOfForm)
{
 var selection = document['nameOfForm'].nameOfInput.selectedIndex;
}
```

... but no joy.

So, where am I going wrong?

For bonus points... what if both the name of the form and the name of the particular input were both dynamic? Then what?

```
function myAwesomeFunction(nameOfForm, nameOfInput)
{
 var selection = document[nameOfForm][nameOfInput].selectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Look them up in the forms object</strike> - this won't work since it is an array and not an object.

use `document.getElementsByName`

```
function myAwesomeFunction(nameOfForm, nameOfInput)
{
 var selection = document.getElementsByName(nameOfForm)[nameOfInput].selectedIndex;
}
```

or even better, set an id attribuite on the form and use `document.getElementById` to find the form

Comment: Actually, the first version you had, document.forms[nameOfForm][nameOfInput].selectedIndex, seems to work fine. At least in my code it's working.

Comment: It probably won't work in all browsers, if you choose to use it, test it thoroughly :)

Comment: Gotcha. I switched to document.getElementsByName(nameOfForm)[nameOfInput] in hopes of better cross browser goodnes. So far, seems to work great. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.getElementById(nameOfForm)` (if you have the ID on the form as well)...

If you can include a jQuery reference to your page, you can easily do the following (again assuming you have the ID on the form):

```
function myAwesomeFunction(nameOfForm, nameOfInput)
{
  var form = $("form#" + nameOfForm);
  var input = $("#" + nameOfInput + ":input");
  var selection = $(input).val();
}
```

Comment: This will not work cross browser, only ie is crazy enough to match the name attribute when calling getElementById

Comment: I modified my suggestion with a jQuery example.

Answer (score -1):

function focusElement(formName, elemName) {
    var elem = document.forms[formName].elements[elemName];
}
try this
formname is name of the form and elemname is input label name

Comment: Doesn't work since document.forms is an array and you need to do lookups by index and not name